# Elderfang Venom vs Board wipe

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Elderfang Venom](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elderfang%20Venom) and 10 elves are on the board and all non-land permanents are destroyed. Does the Elderfang Venom still trigger for all the elves dying at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, each permanent that dies sees each other permanent dying at the same time. Elderfang Venom will trigger 10 times.**

> 603.10a Some zone-change triggers look back in time. These are leaves-the-battlefield abilities, abilities that trigger when a card leaves a graveyard, and abilities that trigger when an object that all players can see is put into a hand or library.

> Example: Two creatures are on the battlefield along with an artifact that has the ability “Whenever a creature dies, you gain 1 life.” Someone casts a spell that destroys all artifacts, creatures, and enchantments. The artifact’s ability triggers twice, even though the artifact goes to its owner’s graveyard at the same time as the creatures.